# JNI: Given jobject, obtain its cached method

Tags: java, c++, caching, optimization, java-native-interface

In Java, I have an interface:

```
public interface I {...}
```

declaring a function `void f()`, and some classes:

```
public class A implements I {...}
public class B implements I {...}
public class C implements I {...}
...
```

I often call the native function:

```
public native void nativeFunc(I obj);
```

---

In C++, I obtain a

```
jobject jobj
```

The purpose is to call

```
jobj.f();
```

without going every time through the chain

```
cls = jenv->GetObjectClass(jobj);           (1)
mid = jenv->GetMethodID(cls, "f", "()V");   (2)
jenv->CallVoidMethod(jobj, mid);            (3)
```

---

I can't seem to cache `mid` between native calls. As another suggestion, I could start with line (1), then use a cached `map <jclass, jmethodID>`. However, this probably won't work, too, since `jclass` references might differ for the same class.

Is there any optimizing solution?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your program and the number of classes implementing 'interface I', as well as the number of class loaders available (that can multiply the number of classes) you can decide to create a global reference to those classes

```
jclass globalRefCls = jni->NewGlobalRef(localRefCls);
```

Then you can cache those instances and the jmethodID in a map for later use.

UPDATE

After the talk in the comments, I re-read your requirements.
As long as you get a jobject every time, you need to get the jclass out **anyway**, your map can also be map where the string is the descriptor of the class.

Everytime you get a jobject, extract the jclass and asks for it's name (you can cache java/lang/Class getName method).

You can also create this cache up front it you'd like, since you know which objects to expect (the ones implement I)

Having said that, I guess it won't be as efficient as checking IsSameObject.

Comment: Chen, if you suggest caching classes `A, B, C...` by their `jclass` references, then it won't work, as I wrote at the end of my question. Caching any references (either local or global) in a map is no good, since different references to the same Java class/object might differ in values!

Comment: Why do you think caching a global reference to a class may differ? Are you using a VM that can unload classes? or a VM that loads multiple classes via different class loaders?

Comment: Read two paragraphs starting with "All JNI methods accept..." under "Local and Global References" part of [Android JNI tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#local_and_global_references).

Comment: This doesn't apply to jclass since you can't create two Class objects of the same type without using different class loaders.

Comment: I'm afraid this does apply to classes. I've just run a test. I've made a call `jclass c0 = jenv->GetObjectClass(jobj);` Then, I've made a 100 calls `jclass c1 = jenv->GetObjectClass(jobj);` Comparison (c0 == c1) gives false (probably, for all 100 cases), and IsSameObject(c0, c1) gives true. This test is done in one native function, right after it starts, as one block of code.

Comment: The jclass will not have the same address (that is what == checks between pointers as jclass/jobjects are) and you shouldn't care about it either. What you want is a valid jclass that can be used in JNI functions later on in your program and by making it a global reference it will.

Comment: The point is that it's ONE class object, not two, - but it's many references to that class, different in value, created by different calls to GetObjectClass() for the same object. It's how JNI works...

Comment: What I want is not what you think. I want to cache not one class but many - any Java class (`A, B, C...`) that could implement interface `I`. These classes will repeat many times, this is why I want to cache them, but they are several, not one. So I have to first obtain object's class and then to obtain it's cached info.

Comment: Chen, thanks for your efforts to help. I thought of obtaining the name of the class and making it the key for the map. However, this is much more time-consuming: 1) The chain is `Object.getClass().getName()`, and I can't cache much here, this is already worse than cycling througn the Storage locally; 2) Even after obtaining `jstring` with the name  I have to call `GetStringUTFChars()` to retrieve `const char*`... Too much work.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions that I can think of is to cache classes `A, B, C, ...` by their `jclass` references into any data structure (array, list, whatever; map is no speed-up here). Let's call this structure a Storage. Then I could optimize step (2) and have the following chain:

```
(1) ... (obtain jcls)
(2) for(jclass jclsStored : Storage) {
        if(IsSameObject(jcls, jclsStored))
        {
            mid = ...;
            classFound = true;
        }
    }
    if(!classFound)
        Storage.add(necessary info);
(3) ...
```

I.e. I use JNI

```
IsSameObject()
```

function to bypass different `jclass` values for the same class. If `IsSameObject()` is quick, then this makes an optimization.